# How to Stub Non-ActiveRecord Models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model like this:

```
class Thing
  class << self
    def do_stuff(param)
      result1 = method_one(param)   
      result2 = method_two(result1)
    end

    def method_one(param)
      # tranformation
    end 

    def method_two(result1)
      # transformation
    end
  end
end
```

How can I test that `do_stuff` is properly executing the methods of `method_one` and `method_two` with the right arguments?  I have tried mock_model / mock_class but those don't make any sense to me. I have read the documentation but I'm still having a hard time making sense of it.

My test looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Thing, type: :model do
  let!(:param) { create(:param) }

  describe '#do_stuff' do
    thing = double('thing')
    expect(thing).to receive(:method_one).with param
    thing.do_stuff param
  end
end
```

Why does this not work? 
The error I receive is that thing received an unexpected message param.  But it was quite expected and that was the test.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't double your model. Following example works for me:

```
class Thing
  class << self
    def do_stuff(param)
      result1 = method_one(param)
      result2 = method_two(result1)
    end

    def method_one(param)
      param[:foo]
    end

    def method_two(result1)
      # transformation
      result1
    end
  end
end

# thing_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Thing, type: :model do
  let!(:param) { {foo: "bar"} }

  describe '#do_stuff' do
    it 'should do stuff' do
      expect(Thing).to receive(:method_one).with(param)
      Thing.do_stuff param
    end
  end
end
```

Test result

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/workspace/tapp]$ be rspec spec/models/thing_spec.rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /Users/retgoat/workspace/tapp/config/environments/test.rb:16)
.

Finished in 0.0069 seconds (files took 1.78 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: exactly. to put it more succintly, class methods must be stubbed against the class, not the instance.

Comment: Excellent thank you!  That makes sense (also appreciate taking the time to run the test!).